# JOLT transform to filter JSON array based on object property

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

In my Nifi dataflow, I'm attempting to filter and transform JSON using the JOLT processor, so I'm very new to this.

My input JSON is

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1cca9371-b0f2-4c4d-9028-cd534edfecc9",
    "code": "X00615",
    "url": "https://acme.com.az/043f00e8-7db8-4cab-bc1d-5a39b0a89882"
  },
  {
    "id": "4dcacd3d-dbc8-424d-8f13-46706322a4d3",
    "code": "X01337"
  },
  {
    "id": "d5d86231-3180-4436-867b-6889ae7bd80a",
    "code": "X02732",
    "url": "https://acme.com.az/32853ca4-309c-462b-afc4-b56fd4788e8d"
  }
]
```

and my expected output JSON is

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1cca9371-b0f2-4c4d-9028-cd534edfecc9",
    "code": "X00615",
    "url": "https://acme.com.az/043f00e8-7db8-4cab-bc1d-5a39b0a89882"
  },
  {
    "id": "d5d86231-3180-4436-867b-6889ae7bd80a",
    "code": "X02732",
    "url": "https://acme.com.az/32853ca4-309c-462b-afc4-b56fd4788e8d"
  }
]
```

Thus I want to remove elements that are missing a `url` entry, or put another way, only keep elements that have a `url` value starting with `http`.

I am able to get just the `url` elements in an array, using

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        // "id": "[&1].id", // array grows 
        // "code": "[&1].code", // array grows
        "url": {
          "htt*": {
            "$": "[].&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But when I try to include the other properties/values, the array grows to be 4 elements and not 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following spec will filter the objects containing the key **url** which has values starts with **http**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "@1,url"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "http*": "[]" //only url starting with http will be listed
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can make the keys of objects the values of **url** attributes

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "@1,url"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]" //this square brackets are needed for the cases with the arrays 
                //having totally one url attribute throughout the whole JSON value
    }
  }
]
```

this way, the objects which don't have a url attribute vanish spontaneously.

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: I get the keys but due to constraints of running this in Apache Nifi, that won't fit the data model Nifi uses - it expects a flat JSON array ("infer schema" requires it).  Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

I also came up with a solution just after posting that is different to the provided answers. So providing it for comments/discussion as it uses just a single `shift` operation.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "url": {
          "": null,
          // In other case pass thru
          "*": {
            "@2": "[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]